# Split String base on 2 different char into 1 array variable on c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
str = "Execution {Virtuosity, fluidity, synchronization and dynamism|Projection, expression, costume, & audience impact}";

temp = str.Split('{');
final = temp[1].Split('|');
```

as my code snippet i can't deny that its for lazy people :D

can i possible split with 2 char? split with '{' and '|' and remove the last char '}'.

confuse? here's what i want to happen.

from

```
str = "Execution {Virtuosity, fluidity, synchronization and dynamism|Projection, expression, costume, & audience impact}";
```

to

```
final[] = {"Execution","Virtuosity, fluidity, synchronization and dynamism","Projection, expression, costume, & audience impact"};
```

anyone can help please.

Comment: if input is `str = "AA|BB{CC|DD}"` what is your expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using another overload of [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string str = "Execution {Virtuosity, fluidity, synchronization and"
           + " dynamism|Projection, expression, costume, & audience impact}";
string[] final = str.Split(new char[] { '{', '}', '|' },
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                 );
```